# What would be a good book for optics?

Tags: optics, books

I would like to refresh my knowledge about optics. I studied optics back in the university but I almost forgot everything. What would be a good book to do that?

Comment: Is there an answer provided here yet, or are you still looking for a better answer? Id someone has resolved your issue, could you select that answer as "Accepted"?

Comment: @jrista I'm actually still looking for a better answer. I know that it's better to accept a question as soon as we find a good one, this is my approach in general because this is the idea of this website in the first place. The problem with books questions is that it's subjective from person to person

Comment: Well, its actually not necessary to accept right away. On the contrary, if you need a better answer, you should wait for one to be offered...once an answer is accepted, that often tends to kill off the opportunity to get any more. I'll start a bounty on this, hopefully that will bring in more answerers.

Comment: @jrista Thanks! I agree with you that's why I didn't mark any as accepted answer

Comment: Hmm...I thought I had a bounty on this question. It seems to have disappeared though, and no one was awarded?

Comment: @jrista that's weird

Comment: Well, my 100 bounty seems to have been an utter waste...rep down the tube. SE really needs to fix bounty....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching this for a while, here is the list that I think it may be interesting:

- [Optics in Photography](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0819407631): Explains fundamental optical principles that apply to photography
- [Optics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805385665): Elementary intro to optics
- [Introduction to Optics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131499335): Elementary intro to optics
- [Introduction to Modern Optics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486659577): Less comprehensive that [Optics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805385665) but much cheaper
- [Applied Photographic Optics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0240515404): Related directly to photography. The reason it's not on top of the list is because it's more complicated than others, not elementary. It was selected by the American Library Association's 'Choice' magazine as "best technical book".
- [Modern Optical Engineering](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071476873): Technical book as the previous one.
- [Photographic Optics: A Text Book for the Professional and Amateur](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1149675128): you can find this book free on [Google books](http://books.google.com/books/about/Photographic_optics.html?id=Sz4JAAAAIAAJ).

Answer (score 5):

There are couple of them, but you can start with these:

- [Optics in Photography (SPIE Press Monograph Vol. PM06)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0819407631): 
  Explains fundamental optical principles that apply to photography, cameras, and lenses. Intended for professionals and serious amateur photographers as well as lens designers and optical engineers.

  Contents

  - Perspective
  - Light Rays and Lens Aberrations
  - Light Waves and How They Behave
  - Definition and Resolution
  - Depth of Field
  - The Brightness of Images
  - Types of Photographic Objectives
  - Lens Attachments
  - Enlarging and Projection Systems
  - Stereoscopic Photography
  - Shutters and Flash
  - Camera Viewfinders and Rangefinders

    [image]
- [The Optics of Photography and Photographic Lenses](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1421248514)

  [image: You can find a description on Google Books]

One of my friend has these books and I have find them very useful many times.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what level of the treatment you are looking for, and if you want to go really at the foundations, you could try [the classic by Born and Wolf](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521642221), Principles of Optics. Great book.

A short excerpt from the Table of contents:

- Foundations of geometrical optics
- Geometrical theory of optical imaging
- Geometrical theory of aberrations
- Image forming instruments

and much, much more.

Answer (score 1):

For a university level optics book, Hecht is excellent. It's what I used in university years ago (that was an earlier edition though).

[Optics-4th-Edition-Eugene-Hecht](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805385665)

Answer (score -1):

[OPTICKS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1591020956) can get you all the way to the source... As well as teach you some concepts (in a rather archaic but interesting way) it will expose a hint to the mind of a great(est) scientist.

Comment: Your answer was not helpful. The question wasn't about outdated 17th century works that deal exclusively with a corpuscular theory of light.

Comment: @ysap: Opinions happen, downvotes happen. Accept it and move along.

Comment: @jrista - you know that it is not about the downvote itself - and we had this discussion in the past. I would like to get the community to the point were it is *constructive*. People should explain why they are downvoting (especially when it is the 1st vote, later downvoters may just join that opinion and it is OK). This way the poster can benefit from a good criticism and possibly improve his answer, or learn something new.

Comment: Newton's corpuscular theory addresses the geometric optics, as you say, but not wave phenomena like diffraction, which I would consider important in a general recommendation to somebody who wants to learn optics. More generally, I don't think very old books are a good way to learn a topic. As a historical curiosity later? Sure. But not for learning. This is my opinion, and it's reflected in my vote. If other people think *Opticks* is a great way to learn the subject, they can vote accordingly.

Comment: @coneslayer - I appreciate your comment and opinion wholeheartedly. Note that my original complain was not about the downvote, but the lack of explanation. I guess that to the OP it is not less important to understand *why* you think it is not a good reference, right? So, let's finish this argument as friends, OK?

Comment: @ysap: There is always an ideal, but ideals need to be balanced with the reality of things. I'd love PhotoSE to be an open, objective community that always discussed the merits of everything, but the core of our subject matter often begs for the opposite. We cannot force voters to explain their votes, nor should we. I think coneslayer has been *more than open* in offering his opinion, and you should welcome that when it occurs.

Comment: @coneslayer without entering the debate on the merit of Opticks, very old books are usually much more than "historical curiosities". In the case of Galilei, Newton, Maxwell, Einstein (and others, obviously the list is very short), they are often, in my opinion, masterpieces to be studied deeply and known by heart.

Comment: Btw +1 from me, for the hint to the mind of Newton :)

Comment: I've removed combative comments and cleaned up the ones that remain. Try to just roll with the punches in the future, and if you really need to ask for a reason for a downvote, ask politely.

Comment: @jrista A perfect example, someone down voted the question without specifying any reason :)

Comment: @AkramMellice - go figure...